# Adding CVS perspective for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I do not have the CVS perspective in eclipse (downloaded from the android developer site)

Can I add the same via any plugin or Help->Install new software?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not under:

```
Window -> Show view -> Other -> CVS -> CVS repository
```

As far as I now it's included by default on the Eclipse Java IDE.